# How to install TexStudio on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, latex

I found this [page](https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/xenial/texstudio) which suggests to install TexStudio with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install texstudio
```

Is it enough? Don't I need a package manager like `MiKTeX` in Windows?

Thanks,

Comment: With `apt-get` you are using the package manager.

Comment: I did it from Ubuntu Software center, it seems it lack a few things such as the top banner ... Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Just to confirm ... yes this is the best latex editor as of 20220810 for Ubuntu

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When I installed Texmaker then that was all I needed to do. Any dependencies should be automatically installed when you use apt-get. I remember being surprised how much more work I had to do to install it on Windows.

Comment: You're right, when I tried the second command, it told me it needed 610MB disk space, so yes, it installs all the dependencies with it apparently.

Answer (score 23):

Yes you have to install `texlive-full`, it is around `3.5 GB`. To install it, run the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt install texlive-full
```

Then you can install `texstudio` or `texmaker`.

Source [here](http://milq.github.io/install-latex-ubuntu-debian/)

Comment: +1. Funny, this is actually *the only* correct answer and it was downvoted :). Though one can install `texstudio` alone, it will be pretty useless because one can't compile real latex documents with it; instead of installing `texlive-full` one can install `texlive`and additional packages, such as `texlive-latex-extra` (given one knows what he needs).

Comment: Will MikTex for ubuntu work instead of texlive?

Comment: "E: Failed to fetch http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libosmesa6_18.2.2-0ubuntu1~18.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 109.202.202.202 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/poppler/libpoppler-qt5-1_0.62.0-2ubuntu2.6_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 109.202.202.202 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?"
Any advice?

Comment: @Kvothe Well have you tried running `run apt-get update`?

Answer (score 4):

It is also possible to install it via the **Ubuntu Software** program, which might be easier for people that are new to Ubuntu.

1. Open Ubuntu Software
2. Search TeXstudio
3. Press install and wait

Answer (score 4):

Texstudio is merely an IDE. 
To get the full advantage of installing latex, you will have to use the command:

```
sudo apt install texlive-full  // for ubuntu 16.04 and above
```

However, the above command can most often be a temptation. It installs so many extra (language) packages, most of which will be unnessary for your purpose. Therefore, it is recommended to use the command without the "full":

```
sudo apt install texlive   // for ubuntu 16.04 and above
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

When installing texstudio, you need to install texlive first, since texstudio is solely the "IDE"

Comment: While this may solve the issue, I would still recommend including instructions on how to install `texlive` with `texstudio` so that this will be a more useful answer for those who need it.

Answer (score 3):

**BRIEF**

I've seen 2 types of answers here. Both answers are actually OK. You could just do as you say or install first `texlive-full`.

- Option 1: `sudo apt-get install texstudio` will have texstudio using
  `texlive-base`.
- Option 2: `sudo apt install texlive-full` + `sudo apt-get install texstudio` will have texstudio using `texlive-full`

Both will have texstudio up and running and for most cases, the first option will be enough to compile. Option 2 will install every package so you'll never have to install any extra package when compiling.

I guess if you don't have space issues the second option is better. However, I am using Ubuntu on a live persistent USB drive without much space so I go for option 1.

You could check packages differences running `apt-cache search texlive` **(you'll see that there are actually more than 2 options)**.